# Partial data sets in R

Tags: r, statistics

We are looking to train R with structures like:
age, data1, data2, ... dataN, actions

where N depends on the amount of data we have about a person.

Our goal is to determine how likely is it that another person would generate actions by querying on all the data we have him/her.

age, data1, data2, ...dataM where M could be bigger or smaller than N.

With complete data-sets we could have used binary logistic regression. But we need to use partial sets.

What's the best way to calculate the likelihood that a person performs actions by asking with partial data sets?

Comment: Wild guess: you're trying some bootstrapping procedure? You might have better luck on http://stats.stackexchange.com and with a bit more explanation about the setup. You don't have to bootstrap manually, there are frameworks for that in R.

Comment: Updated with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hmisc package provides several multiple imputation functions, providing a means to gain more complete use of the information that is present in your data.

```
require(Hmisc)
?aregImpute  # with several worked examples
```

The accompanying package, rms, has a binary logistic regression function:

```
require(rms)
?lrm
```

Comment: I think the boot package is more what he's looking for. Imputation is for missing data especially, bootstrapping is something else.